# Word 2010 generated PDF: corrupted copy-paste and search text

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a .doc (it was created with a previous word version) file and I'm exporting it to PDF with Word 2010. The PDF looks fine but when I select something like "The red fox jumped over the lazy dog" and I copy-paste it into a text editor like notepad, I get

> The red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox
>   jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red
>   fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedThe
>   red fox jumpedThe red fox jumpedover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover
>   the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover
>   the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover
>   the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dogover
>   the lazy dogover the lazy dogover the lazy dog

plus finding text into the PDF doesn't work: Adobe Reader shows a rectangle in a page of the PDF where there's no text. I think it is probably finding all those multiple instances of the text.

How can I solved this? Exporting the PDF with Word 2007 works fine, has something changed with 2010?

Comment: Do you see "Compatibility mode" at the  top of the window? If so, can you try re-saving the file in the most recent `.docx` format and then save the pdf again?